# VBA Inserts extra parenthesis when copying Module to Another WorkBook

Tags: excel, vba

So as the title states VBA is adding an extra set of parenthesis after it moves code over. Why does it do this? And how do i make it stop?

Here is code moving the module:

```
Set src = ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("Module2").CodeModule
Set dest = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("Sheet2") _
.CodeModule

dest.DeleteLines 1, dest.CountOfLines
dest.AddFromString src.Lines(1, src.CountOfLines)
```

Here is the code after the output:

```
Private Declare Function ShellExecute Lib "shell32.dll" _
Alias "ShellExecuteA" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal lpOperation As String, _
ByVal lpFile As String, ByVal lpParameters As String, ByVal lpDirectory As String, _
ByVal nShowCmd As Long) As Long

 Private Sub MESSAGEBERX()
      MsgBox ("You did it")
 End Sub
 ()
```

EDIT

turns out I left out the the stuff at the top. It also turns out that the culprit was it. Is it due to the "private function" part? I am still messing around with it but still cant get it to move over without the extra parentheses...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No idea where the extra parentheses come from - that looks like a bug in the VBE. An easy work-around is to use `InsertLines` instead of `AddFromString`:

```
Set src = ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("Module2").CodeModule
Set dest = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("Sheet2") _
.CodeModule

dest.DeleteLines 1, dest.CountOfLines
dest.InsertLines 1, src.Lines(1, src.CountOfLines)
```

Comment: IDK why i was using add from string, that just seems backwards. But then again I am just learning the ropes here on this particular issue. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem.
Another workaround is to make the declare part at the top one line, i.e., without "_".